# Unable to add integer values in Java

Tags: java, android, variables, integer

What I want is that by default C is 0 but when the user adds 2 then it should display 2 and then when the user adds 4 it should be 6 but instead it displays 4
Any help would be appreciated!

```
    public void addCash(View view) {
    //Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);

    EditText val1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num);
    int b = 0;
    int a = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int d = 0;

    a = Integer.parseInt(val1.getText().toString());

     if (c == 0) {
         c = a + b;
     }
     else {
         c = c + a;
     }

    TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outPut);
    result.setText(""+c);

    //startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: You always initialize `c` to `0`.

Comment: You need `c` to be an _instance variable_ in an object, not a local variable in a method.  If it's a local variable in a method, you can't retain the value between method calls.  The value goes away as soon as `addCash` is done.

Comment: post your complete class

Comment: Also, what's the point of `c = a + b` if `b` can never be anything other than 0?  You could just say `c = a`.  But since you only do this if `c == 0`, saying `c = a` is exactly the same as `c = c + a`.  In other words, this whole `if` statement is redundant.  Also, what is `d` there for?

Comment: How to make C an Instance Variable

Comment: I have removed the D , it was from earlier code

Comment: @MusaUsman I think you really need to read more about [classes and methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html).

Comment: @MCEmperor It's been a week since I started programming Java

Comment: @MusaUsman I see, so I don't blame you. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

variable c is local to this function and every time function is called it initialize c = 0 .

So every time only if condition will run.

else condition will never executed.

you can declare c as global ....

Comment: How to declare C as global int?

Comment: for global declaration you have to declare c when your class start..          Eg : class Test { private int c; Test(){c=0;} fun(){  //use c } }

Answer (score 0):

Initialize "c" as a global member variable of your activity.Because instance of this will remain throughout the activity whereas if you initialize it as local vairable every time when you call method new variable instance is created

This as the global instance inside your activity

```
private int c = 0;
```

These "a",b","d" be initialzed again and again when call addcash method

```
public void addCash(View view) {
//Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);

EditText val1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num);

int b = 0;
int a = 0;
int d = 0;

a = Integer.parseInt(val1.getText().toString());

 if (c == 0) {
     c = a + b;
 }
 else {
     c = c + a;
 }

TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outPut);
result.setText(""+c);
```

Also replace below line of code with c = c + a as "b" will be always zero according to your code

```
if (c == 0) 
{
   c = a + b;
}
```

For more information check this link

```
http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week3/11.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your variable `c` with the value of the textview like this:

```
TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outPut);
int c = Integer.parseInt(val1.getText().toString());
```

Edit: if the TextView by default is not set to 0 then you should consider doing an additional check.

Comment: How to set it to default 0?

Comment: @MusaUsman In the Activity's onCreate method add this: `TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outPut);
    result.setText("0");`

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers already stated, you are using local variables, which are initialized at each method call.

```
class SomeActivity {

    private int c = 3; // Instance variable being initialized to 3. When you
                       // leave out the "= 3" part, then it is initialized
                       // to 0.

    public void addCash(View v) {
        // Now if you add something to c, it will persist between multiple
        // method calls
        EditText inputField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num);
        EditText outputField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outPut);
        c += Integer.parseInt(inputField.getText().toString());
        outputField.setText(String.valueOf(c));
    }
}
```